# MSSQL Server - get a whole part of a decimal value in the computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

Here's my simplified table (SQL Server 2005):

```
table1: col1 int, col2 int, col3 cast(col1/col2 as int) [computed column]
```

for some reason the above doesn't work. i just want to save a WHOLE part of col1/col2, how do i do that?

```
example: col1 = 5, col2 = 3 ... col3 should be 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the [floor function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx):

FLOOR(col1/col2)

or

CONVERT(int, FLOOR(col1/col2)) -- Might be overkill

Comment: what result are you getting when you do col1/col2 ?

Comment: nevermind ... i got the columns mixed up ... floor() works just fine